# Office 365 global admin still get access error on navigation elements

Tags: sharepoint-online, access, access-denied, current-navigation

I am global admin on office 365 template and also part of site collection admin on the site collection. I created the site myself but now it doesn't allow me to change Navigation settings on site, it give we access error.Before i open ticket to msft i wanted to reach out to community.

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the scripting capabilities is turned off in your site.

Whenever you create a new site, the custom scripting capabilities are turned off by default. You need to enable the custom scripting capabilities to have the ability to managed navigation.

**Option 1**: Go to SharePoint admin center > settings. In the settings page, in the Custom Script section, set the values to allow as in below image:

[image]

Now, you need to wait 24 hours for the scripting capabilities to be enabled. After that is turned on, you will be able to save the settings.

**Option 2** : Using SharePoint Online PowerShell

After opening the SPO PowerShell, run the below commands:

```
Connect-SPOService -Url "https://tenantname-admin.sharepoint.com"

Set-SPOSite "https://tenantname.sharepoint.com/sites/test" -DenyAddAndCustomizePages 0
```

Once you have executed these commands, it will be reflected immediately and you don't need to wait for 24 hours.

Download link- SPO PowerShell:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=35588

PS - You require SharePoint admin credentials for the above mentioned steps. Site Collection admin wont work.